# How can I edit and save configuration env variable of a azure function app using python 3?

Tags: python, azure

I am working on a project where I have to edit and save azure function variable using python3 in a set of time period(Azure Timer Trigger).
I use this to get the env variable,

```
import os
departmentid = str(os.getenv("departmentID"))
```

But it is able to get not to do any edit...
and I got this also,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-python#update-a-configuration-setting

But it is working in Azure App Config not in Azure App Function.
Can anyone suggest a solution to edit and save new value to particualr env keys using python3?

Comment: Have you gone this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=azurecli-linux%2Capplication-level#environment-variables) does this helpful ?

Comment: it is useful,but still doesn't have explanation about how can i edit and save new value to a env value of azure function app configuration @VenkateshDodda-MT

Comment: are you trying to change those env app settings values from the portal or you are trying to change them through local.settings.json? Do you want to edit those env app setting values during runtime ?

Comment: My usecase is to change and save one env value every sunday using azure TImer Trigger @VenkateshDodda-MT

Answer (score 0):

Environment Variables are configured for the Function App in Azure Functions from portal and can be accessible by all functions within that app. They are set from the 'Configuration' tab of the left pane's Settings.

[image: Application settings in Function App]

Provide a name and a value of your variable to add your own application setting by clicking on `New application setting` and Then click on ‘Save’.

[image: Adding an application setting]

[image: Saving the settings]

and then try the below code within your function code to access the environment variable.

```
import os new_db_flag = int(os.environ["NEW_DB_FLAG"])
```

To edit the same you can navigate to the configurations page -> click on the variable that you wanted to change -> edit the value of it and click save.

[image]

> **NOTE:** If your Function app runs on Consumption plan then it allows only one [deployment slot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-slots).

**REFERENCES:**
[How to set Environment Variables in Azure Functions](https://iotespresso.com/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-azure-functions/)

Comment: I need an auto editing using python code not manual edit.